# Имитатор браузера

Tags: javascript, c#, веб-программирование

Добрался до самой сложной части проекта. Нужно получать информацию из сайта который целиком и полностью построен на js(на zepto если быть конкретней). Браузер отправляет запрос циклично, получает таблицу. Мне нужны данные из таблицы + нажать на кнопку в этой таблице(кнопки так же генерируются динамически, привязаны к js) Вероятно новый экземпляр таблицы можно получить путем перезагрузки, но как жать на кнопку не знаю. Тут бы какой-то программный имитатор браузера или что-то около того. Подскажите, есть ли такая библиотека на c#. Понять что творят местные скрипты никак не могу..

Comment: CefSharp? GeckoFX?

Comment: Пробовали Selenium?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону selenium

Comment: Спасибо. С Selenium имел когда-то дело, но очень давно. Про CefSharp и GeckoFX вообще не слышал. Пойду пробовать.